# Java: Error reading FileInputStream

Tags: java, eclipse, fileinputstream

I have `Stemmer` class which has the method `ExecuteStem` as follows.

```
public class Stemmer implements Stemmer2 {       
public static void ExecuteStem(String[] args) throws IOException{
Stemmer s = new Stemmer();

for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
  try {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[i]);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferLen, offset, ch;

    bufferLen = in.read(buffer);
    offset = 0;
    s.reset();

    while(true) {
      if (offset < bufferLen)
        ch = buffer[offset++];
      else {
        bufferLen = in.read(buffer);
        offset = 0;
        if (bufferLen < 0)
          ch = -1;
        else
          ch = buffer[offset++];
      }

      if (Character.isLetter((char) ch)) {
        s.add(Character.toLowerCase((char) ch));
      }
      else {
         s.stem();
         System.out.print(s.toString());
         s.reset();
         if (ch < 0)
           break;
         else {
           System.out.print((char) ch);
         }
       }
    }

    in.close();
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("error reading " + args[i]);
  }
}
}
```

I want to call `ExecuteStem` method from the class `CallMethod`. So CallMethod.java is as follows.

```
public class CallMethod {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] t={"Singing and Dancing"};
    Stemmer.ExecuteStem(t);
}
```

When this code is run, "error reading singing and dancing" gets printed. Why won't it read "FileInputStream"?

Comment: Do you have a file called Singing and Dancing?

Comment: Also, why don't you add `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block so you can see the original error message?

Comment: And Singing and Dancing is a file in the current working directory?

Comment: No, I passed it as a string array. Actually, I want to pass the content in a file by giving its url.

Comment: The parameter to `new FileInputStream()` is the *name* of a file, not the content to be read.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `InputStream` with `FileInputStream` and changed the code as follows.

```
public static void ExecuteStem() throws IOException{
Stemmer s = new Stemmer();

FileInputStream fin= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\input.txt");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fin);
```

And I changed the `CallMethod` class as follows:

```
public class CallMethod {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Stemmer.ExecuteStem();
}
}
```

This worked!

Comment: [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) is for reading a binary file, not a `.txt` file. Get rid of it!